# Least distance error between two lines

Tags: matlab

I have two plotted lines and I want to find the least distance error between them. When I simply subtract them from each other I get the error in the x-direction. But I am looking for the error in the least distance way between the two lines.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Best regards,
Gidi

Comment: How do yo "subtract" two lines? What do you subtract, specifically? How do you define the lines (which parameters)?

Answer (score 1):

With `d = pdist2(L1, L2, 'euclidean', 'smallest', 1);` you get a vector `d` with the distance from each point in `L2` to it's closest neighbor in `L1`. Then, the shortest distance will be `min(d)`.

I am assuming that both `L1` and `L2` are n-by-2 and m-by-2 with m and n being the number of points (n and m are allowed to be different). From your comment I would guess you had not included the x-component. To fix that, you could say `L1 = [y_n, u_new]` and likewise for `L2` from `z`, assuming `y_n` was the x-component. If `y_n` is a row vector, you should transpose it as in `L1 = [y_n', u_new]`.

If you wish to plot the minimum distance for each point and both lines, `plot(y_n, [u_new, z, d])` should work. Again here, check the orientation of your vectors.

Comment: Hi Again, after from trying with this function it still is not working properly can you maybe tell me what is wrong? Here is a part of my code:

u_new = u(:,tt(1)); %(201x1 double)
z = h3; %(201x1 double)
figure;
y_n=[linspace(-1,1,201)]';
d = pdist2(u_new,z,'euclidean','Smallest',1);
plot(d,y_n,u_new,y_n,z,y_n);

This plot shows some lines but it is not correct. And I can't figure out what I did wrong. Thanks!